# hide legend labels if zero data in jquery pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, pie-chart

I am trying to plot a pie chart with data set containing zero values.But pie chart shows only labels till data gets updated.

What if I wanted to show empty pie chart.
[image]

I have given:

```
var data = [
{
    label: "Series1",
    data: 0,
    url: "http://stackoverflow.com"},
{
    label: "Series2",
    data: 0,
    url: "http://serverfault.com"},
{
    label: "Serie3",
    data: 0,
    url: "http://superuser.com"},
{
    label: "Series4",
    data: 0,
    url: "http://www.google.com"},
{
    label: "Series5",
    data: 0,
    url: "http://www.oprah.com"},
{
    label: "Series6",
    data: 0,
    url: "http://www.realultimatepower.net/"}
];
var options = {
    series: {
        pie: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true
    }
};

var plot = $.plot($("#graphLoaderDiv"), data, options);
```

Comment: So you want the labels to only show up if they're non-zero?

Comment: Exactly. Labels should be displayed only if data is non zero...Plzz help me doing this...Thanks in advance...

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging deeper I realized  The best possible solution is to not to show pie chart if your data set values are zero.You either can do it editing following plugin or adding check inside your plotting function.

Download jquery.flot.pie.js from here

> http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=530

Go to line No 411 and modify code as follows.

```
if( isNaN(angle) ) {
    //var html = html = '<span class="pieLabel" id="pieLabelNoData" style="position:absolute;top:20px;left:5px;">There is no available data.</span>';
    //html = target.append(html);
    target.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your label formatter function to return null if the series percent is zero.

Answer (score -1):

you can show empty data like this

```
$piedata="[{label:'no data',data:1}]";
```